# View Designer in Crossplatform project in Visual Studio 2017 don't work

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017

A few days ago install visual studio 2017 enterprise.

When I create a C# Crossplatform project, portable, I find that I can't use the "View Designer" to create the UI of the application. I can manually edit the .xaml file, but it's crazy. The message that gives me Visual Studio is:

"The editor is not available for" C: \ ... \ MainPage.xaml.
 Make sure the application for the file type (.xaml) is installed"

On the other hand, when I created a C# Android project or C# iOS the designer works perfectly.

I clarify that I am working on a clean installation of Windows 10 Pro, completely updated, and Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise with a MSDN license, also, completely updated.

Someone who has gone through the same, or who knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not still a designer for cross-platform XAML: only hand write.
Visual Studio XAML designer, work only with WPF.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/forms-xaml-designer/

Comment: Hi Brummell. Thanks for the reply. Anyway, I find strange that when I create a C# Android project or C# IOS project the designer works perfectly. I really do not see any sense in Visual Studio can't  open the designer when it is a Crossplatform project.

Comment: For the shared UI, Xamarin use a dialect of XAML, but in this time does not exist a designer, like for with native app (iOS, Android, UWP).

Comment: I understand. I hope Microsoft does something respect, it is unacceptable. Thank you, @Brummell.